# Any good research on the comparative rates of CSA in different populations? (religious vs none religious, Mormon, catholic, etc)

Tags: measurement, sexuality, sexual-assault

I'm wondering if there is any good research on the rates of CSA in different populations.

Comment: CSA = Child sexual abuse?  I expect that virtually any proxy of this will massively underestimate (eg, criminal convictions) or overestimate (eg, child pornography) rates.  It's really really hard to get "good research" on anything illegal.

Comment: As @ArnonWeinberg points out, rates of sexual assault are hard to quantify exactly as they rely on reporting and convictions. Even rates for rape of men and women are estimates.

Comment: Difficult, yes, but there is a lot of research on other illegal things, surely there is some rough estimates?

Comment: Another aspect to do with difficulties trying to ascertain the extent of the problem of CSA among the clergy is demonstrated in the [Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(film)) movie based on a true story. When you have the upper levels of the church covering cases up and moving the abusers elsewhere, it makes it even more difficult and adds to the problem. They started investing in Boston and uncovered cases worldwide, including in the UK.